# Conditional probability (Binomial distribution)

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I'm doing an exercise of hypothesis testing with $X_1, \ldots X_{12}$, $X \sim Ber(p)$, $H_0\colon p \leq \frac{1}{2}$, $H_1\colon p > \frac{1}{2}$  and a critical region of 
$C_{\Upsilon}=\{(X_1,\ldots X_{12}) : \sum_{i=0}^{12}x_i >7\}$ and I got a probability that I do not know how to calculate,

$P( \text{Reject}\ H_0 \mid H_0)=P( \sum_{i=0}^{12}x_i > 7 \mid p\leq \frac{1}{2})$

I did it like this:
$P( T >7 \mid p\leq \frac{1}{2})=1-P( T \leq 7 \mid p\leq \frac{1}{2}) = 1-(P( T = 0 \mid p\leq \frac{1}{2}) + \ldots P( T =7\mid p\leq \frac{1}{2}))=1-(\binom{12}{0}\frac{1}{2}^{12}+\ldots +\binom{12}{7}\frac{1}{2}^{12} )=0.806640625=\alpha$

And then I had to obtain the power function but I get the same result as above.

Comment: The power function is a _function_ of the parameter and gives the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when the value of the parameter is (any possible) $p$. So for that, keep $p$ unknown and compute the same conditional probability __in terms of__ $p$.

Comment: And the probability is correct?

Comment: No, $p \le \frac 1 2$ is not the same as $p = \frac 1 2$. For example, it's possible that $p = 0$ too, in which case that probability would be $1$.

Comment: I know, but i don't know how to calculate the $ p \leq \frac{1}{2}$ that was my inicial question.

Comment: By the way, $H_0$ is rejected if the sample point is __in__ the critical region, not outside it. So what you want to compute is $P(T > 7 \mid p \le \frac 1 2)$ (and similarly $P( T > 7 \mid p = p_0 )$ for any $p_0$ (to get the power function).

Comment: Well, you can't compute the probability of rejecting $H_0$ when $p \le \frac 1 2$, but you can compute the maximum (or supremum) of this probability. In this case, that probability is maximum when $p = \frac 1 2$ (as you decrease the value of $p$, the probability of $H_0$ being rejected decreases). Very likely, whatever book you're using defines the significance level $\alpha$ as this maximum value.

Comment: Isn't $T \sim BINOM(12, .5)$ under equality in $H_0?$ Then R code `1 - pbinom(7, 12, .5)` returns 0.1938477, and `sum(dbinom(8:12, 12, .5))` returns the same. In R, `pbinom` is binomial CDF and `dbinom` is PDF. Also same for `sum(choose(12, 8:12))/2^12`. // Not sure what your power computation look like. Power against what alternative value $> 1/2.?$